# Copy folders by predefined order

Tags: windows, software-rec, file-transfer

Is there any software available for windows where I can specify the copy order or priority of folders.

I come across this situation when I am taking backups and one of my hard drives is failing and my most important data is kept in 5 to 10 folders and the less important is in other folders so I need to tell the software that 
copy the important folders first then the less important ones.

More than copy I think the right word here would be sync, something like what Robocopy does.

I don't think Teracopy has this feature but I'd be happy if I'm proven wrong.

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Related / duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/666112/whats-the-best-tool-to-use-to-automatically-backup-selected-folders-from-window

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: @Jedi Do any of those softwares have a folder priority list, I mean can I select which folders to copy and in which order to  start the copy process?

Comment: @MiguelSanchez softwarerecs are off-topic here as mentioned above. Also, I agree with the answer below, this question indicates an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score 1):

If your hard drive is failing, stop using it and replace it.

I would likely try to create a VHD copy of the drive using disk2vhd.  Or completely pull it offline until I had a new copy and then use a program like RawCopy (free, limited to 2TB and less drives) to copy the disk to the new one.

Continuing to use a failing drive other than trying to get data off it is just foolish in my opinion.

Comment: One thing I love about superuser.com?  They like to de-emphasize things.